# At commands in macros

Tags: macros

Latex gives seemingly unrelated errors if I use a macro with an `@` in it while defining a macro. Errors are consistent across tectonic, pdflatex, and Overleaf, although Overleaf seems to power through the errors and produce a doc anyway.

Drilling down into an error from using `\@whilenum` in a macro definition, I got to the following minimal latex that reproduces the error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@atcommand #1{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mymacro}{
  \newcounter{x}
  \makeatletter
  \@atcommand{\value{x}}
  \makeatother
}
\mymacro
Notempty % Ensure we don't get emptydoc
\end{document}
```

This gives the error:

```
! You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.
\@ ->\spacefactor 
                  \@m {}
l.12 \mymacro
```

Or, if in a `tikzpicture` (as the original snippet was), `Missing number, treated as zero`.

Any of the following prevents there being an error: removing the `@` from both the definition and use of the `atcommand` macro; lifting the definition of `mymacro` outside of a macro and running it directly; and calling `atcommand` with an integer value instead of the value of a counter.

Just curious what is going on. The question originated from a student asking why their document didn't compile: I've given them an alternative way to achieve what they wanted, but I want to get them a solid explanation of what was wrong with their first attempt.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351.

Comment: `\makeatletter` inside the definition is doing nothing, you need it outside the definition

Comment: you should also have `\newcounter` outside the definition, counters are a finite resource and you are allocating a new one on each use

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! That fixed it. Why can't `\makeatletter` be used in a macro definition?

Comment: because the argument has already been scanned and parsed as `\@`  `atcommand` same reason `\verb` can not be used inside an argument

Comment: As a workaround, you could do `\csname @atcommand\endcsname` which instruct TeX to construct (and use) a macro with the name `@atcommand` more or less whatever their catcodes.